# Python unittest task.apply_async()

Tags: python, celery, python-unittest, django-testing, django-tests

Using coverage to look what has to be tested, and coverage shows that next to this has to be tested:
`send_alert.apply_async()`

I know it is celery task, but is there any way to test the line of code?

rest of code to understand logic for test:

```
class SomeView(GenericAPIView)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #some code
        if not value:
           send_alert.apply_async()
           # response
        # not if Response
```

Test written due to first answer

```
    @patch('event.views.send_alert')
    def test_send_alert(self, mock_send):
        data = {some data for post}
        response = self.client.post('/api/{0}/mettings/'.format(self.user), data)
        print(response.json())
        self.assertTrue(mock_send.called)
```

Also i check in view that after task `print('Tasks Passed')` and i see message that tasks passed, but test failed with error `AssertionError: False is not true`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Django, as this is tagged that way.

Decorate your test with:

```
@override_settings(CELERY_EAGER=True)
def test_foo(self):
    # Make your post
```

Or if you just want to test that it is called.

```
from mock import patch

@patch('your_module.your_file.send_alert.apply_async')
def test_foo(self, mock_send):
    # make your post with "value" set to True
    self.assertTrue(mock_send.called)
```

Comment: it works, but how to integrate this for example in post test view, for example if value not `True` this task is called. and test if it was called

Comment: cause this task is applying in view in post  method when some value(what was received)  wasn't true.

Comment: Updated the answer.  The second version with mock should work for your use case.

Comment: Edit question with test code and error that task isn't called, but have to be called cause after  task i see `print`.

Comment: Are you patching in the right place?  `send_alert` is in `component.message.tasks.send_alert`. But your patch should point to `<view module>.<view file>.send_alert`. You need to patch the name space it is imported into.

Comment: change  to `events.views.send_alert` in this file `class SomeView` where that tasks is called, Updated code , same eeror

Comment: My bad.  You need to patch the async method of the task: `    @patch('event.views.send_alert.apply_async')